# module 'torch.optim' has no attribute 'NAdam'

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

`nadam = torch.optim.NAdam(model.parameters())`

This gives the error `AttributeError: module 'torch.optim' has no attribute 'NAdam'`. My PyTorch version is `'1.9.1+cu102'`, the python version is `3.7.11`. VS code does not even suggest the optimizer but the documentation clearly mentions the optimizer. I can import other optimizers like `Adam`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/optim.html

From the official website, NAdam is not among the optimizers in pytorch v 1.9.1.
Try upgrading to v 1.10.0, and your code should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you. Before now I never bothered to check the documentation version

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, NAdam is new in 1.10. It does not show in https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/optim.html?highlight=optim#module-torch.optim

It is in https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10.0/optim.html?highlight=optim#module-torch.optim